Methods for the Global 30m Height Above the Nearest Drainage project
I would like to know the methodology of the Global 30m height above the nearest drainage dataset. This is not peer reviewed with the only link available to a poster on the Research Gate page of the first author.
There is very brief documentation ie metadata of this product available on the awesome-gee-community-catalogue. For example, in the hyperlinked page, information such as cell size (30 and 90m) and river head threshold cells (100 and 1000) has been included, with the latter information about river head threshold not mentioned in the Research Gate poster nor anywhere else. Also the hyperlinked awesome-gee-community catalogue product page has the GEE code link for visualizing the product. The code snippet shows the legend manually typed such as "HAND 100, 30m (~0.1km2)" and "HAND 1000, 30m (~1km2)". There is no information about the sqkm mentioned in parentheses- what is it and where do these numbers come from.
